# For each `pop` get frequencies of the elements of `id`

Tags: r, data.table

Consider this data:

```
m = data.frame(pop=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4),
                id=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2))

> m
   pop id
1    1  0
2    1  1
3    1  1
4    1  1
5    2  1
6    2  1
7    2  0
8    2  2
9    2  1
10   3  1
11   3  1
12   3  2
13   3  1
14   3  2
15   4  2
16   4  2
```

**I would like to get the frequency of each unique `id` in each unique `pop`?** For example, the `id 1` is present 3 times out of 4 when `pop == 1`, therefore the frequency of `id 1` in `pop 1` is 0.75.

I came up with this ugly solution:

```
out = matrix(0,ncol=3)

for (p in unique(m$pop))
{
    for (i in unique(m$id))
    {
        m1  = m[m$pop == p,]
        f   = nrow(m1[m1$id == i,])/nrow(m1)
        out = rbind(out, c(p, f, i))
    }
}
out = out[-1,]
colnames(out) = c("pop", "freq", "id")

# SOLUTION

> out
      pop freq id
 [1,]   1 0.25  0
 [2,]   1 0.75  1
 [3,]   1 0.00  2
 [4,]   2 0.20  0
 [5,]   2 0.60  1
 [6,]   2 0.20  2
 [7,]   3 0.00  0
 [8,]   3 0.60  1
 [9,]   3 0.40  2
[10,]   4 0.00  0
[11,]   4 0.00  1
[12,]   4 1.00  2
```

I am sure there exists a more efficient solution using `data.table` or `table` but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I might do:

```
as.data.frame(prop.table(table(m),1))
#    pop id Freq
# 1    1  0 0.25
# 2    2  0 0.20
# 3    3  0 0.00
# 4    4  0 0.00
# 5    1  1 0.75
# 6    2  1 0.60
# 7    3  1 0.60
# 8    4  1 0.00
# 9    1  2 0.00
# 10   2  2 0.20
# 11   3  2 0.40
# 12   4  2 1.00
```

If you want it sorted by `pop`, you can do that afterwards. Alternately, you could transpose the table with `t` before converting to `data.frame`; or use `rev(m)` and `prop.table` on dimension `2`.

Comment: That looks much better (and is much more efficient) than my for loops. +1 Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
m %>% 
  group_by(pop, id) %>% 
  summarise(s = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = s / sum(s)) %>%
  select(-s)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: pop
#
#  pop id freq
#1   1  0 0.25
#2   1  1 0.75
#3   2  0 0.20
#4   2  1 0.60
#5   2  2 0.20
#6   3  1 0.60
#7   3  2 0.40
#8   4  2 1.00
```

Comment: Thnks for this answer. It indeed doesn't match the desired output though.

Comment: Ok, that matches the solution now. +1 Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(m)[, {div = .N; .SD[, .N/div, keyby = id]}, by = pop]
#   pop id   V1
#1:   1  0 0.25
#2:   1  1 0.75
#3:   2  0 0.20
#4:   2  1 0.60
#5:   2  2 0.20
#6:   3  1 0.60
#7:   3  2 0.40
#8:   4  2 1.00
```

Comment: I wish there was such an elegant way using `dplyr`. I submitted a feature request: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1223

Comment: @StevenBeaupré my limited `dplyr` skills suggest `m %>% group_by(pop) %>% do({div = n(); . %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(n()/div)})` as an analogue. My understanding is that the `dplyr` crowd doesn't like using `do` though (due to performance?).

Comment: Yes `do()` is generaly awfully slow. But I haven't thought of using it for the problem at hand. Interesting. I cannot reproduce your suggestion using `0.4.2`: `Error in n() : This function should not be called directly`

Comment: I'm running version `0.4.1` - no idea what's changed.